# How many files does my browser download at a time when there is a flash movie on the page?

Tags: flash, http, browser, flash-cs5

If I load a web page full of other files, e.g. images, my browser doesn't load them all at once. I seem to remember reading that IE will only have at most 3 requests open at a time for a page. The rest will be queued.

If I have a flash movie on the page which is continually making image requests, how does this affect the maximum number of downloading files in the browser?

- Is this browser limit accurate, and is it generally the same across browsers?
- Does flash share the requests of the browser?
- If not, does flash have a limit and what is that limit?

For some background, I do have a flash movie that is continually loading files so there is a queue of Loaders waiting to make requests. My idea was that if there was a different request that I needed to be executed straight away I could make it jump the queue by making a javascript call and allowing the browser to make the request instead. I'd like to know if this is behaviour I could rely on across browsers out there in the real world.

Comment: afaik video streaming (rtm* protocols and stratus) ignores http request queue. could you provide an example of `different request that I needed to be executed straight away`?

Answer (score 0):

Install Fiddler, it's a "http sniffer" tool. It's a proxy between your browser and the Internet, and it shows you all the http connection running.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/